# C# What is causing my simple messaging server to not respond when i start it

Tags: c#, .net, crash, network-programming

I am very new to networking using c# and for my first taste of it i decided to code a very very simple server program but unfortunately the application stops responding... 
here the server code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stat.Text = "Status";


    }

    private void StatusAndMsg_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void stat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void SetText(string text)
    {

    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.31"), 60000);
            listener.Start();
            StatusAndMsg.Text = "lisening for connection requests";

            while (true)
            {
                StatusAndMsg.Text = "lisening for connection requests";

                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                string s = null;

                while (s != "Exit")
                {
                    StatusAndMsg.Text = "you can now start typing";
                    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                    sw.Flush();
                    StatusAndMsg.Text = "client : " + sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sw.Close();
                sr.Close();
                client.Close();
            }


        }catch (Exception b)
           {
            StatusAndMsg.Text = "error : " + b;
           }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

as you can see everything is tied to a start button before i click the start button everything works fine it write the word "Status" in text box but when i click the start button the window stops responding i cant even press the buttons
or type in the text boxes ive tried changing the port restarting the program  but its still not working i think i have probably made a very newbie mistake and am sorry for that but could someboby please find the reason why the program is not responding so i can continue to learn network programming

thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738104/1432845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did a very common mistake, you have placed the code in an UI event, that means the code is being executed on the UI thread. If you lock that thread with your code (you have an infinite loop) then the UI will never become usable again.

You need to use asynchronous code or a separated thread for this, the "simplest" solution is the thread:

```
private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread listenerThread = new Thread(listen);
    listenerThread.Start();
}

void listen(object State)
{

    try
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.31"), 60000);
        listener.Start();
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {StatusAndMsg.Text = "lisening for connection requests";}));


        while (true)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {StatusAndMsg.Text = "lisening for connection requests";}));

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            string s = null;

            while (s != "Exit")
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {StatusAndMsg.Text = "you can now start typing";}));
                sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                sw.Flush();
                this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {StatusAndMsg.Text = "client : " + sr.ReadLine();}));

            }
            sw.Close();
            sr.Close();
            client.Close();
        }


    }catch (Exception b)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {StatusAndMsg.Text = "error : " + b;}));

    }

}
```

Note also the use of `BeginInvoke` on the secondary thread as you can't interact with main thread from the secondary one.

Comment: If I'm right, `TcpListener` should be closed in a proper way, right? It is not a theme of a question, but it should be corrected.

Comment: I just moved the user's code to solve the problem he described and added the `BeginInvoke` to avoid introducing new bugs, if the user has any other problem he should ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In these cases I usually try to point out possible problems / bad habits / etc. Anyway, this question had a really short livespan, so we probably shouldn't get more attention to it.